# I Want to write a SOQL query to get data starting today and next 365days/last 365days

Tags: datetime, soql

I have tried these queries...

```
SELECT Id__c 
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    Datetime =  Current_Date()
```

this works....

but i want data where date is between Current_Date() and Current_Date()+365 days/Current_Date()-365 days

when i try something like this

```
SELECT Id__c 
FROM 
table
WHERE 
Datetime BETWEEN Current_Date() 
 AND Current_Date()+365/*i think this doesn't work*/
```

I am getting the below error:

Review your expression errors and try again.
1: ADD operator must have Number field on both sides
2: GREATER_THAN operator must have the same type of arguments on both sides

Comment: This is a case when we simply MUST know which dbms you are using. Choose a tag for that dbms (eg mysql ). Date math syntax changes between dbms vendors.

Comment: Sorry misread SOQL

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that you're trying to add a number (365) directly to a date object. And this is because SOQL doesn't support date arithmetic and you might have to use [relative date literals in SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

You should ideally use something like `Datetime >= Current_Date() AND Datetime <= NEXT_N_DAYS:365`

Answer (score 0):

There are specific literals you can use for the date range:

```
SELECT Id__c
FROM table
WHERE Datetime BETWEEN LAST_N_DAYS:365 and NEXT_N_DAYS:365
```

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm